# How do i edit text that is not in the customization menu

Tags: customization, text

So i wanted to edit this text on my website and i tried to edit the service section but it did not have this specific section there. I looked around wordpress and i couldn't find it anywhere.

This is my website http://sherrysanimalkookies.com/

On the kookie section under custom dog kookies i want to edit the text where it said pick it up at winter garden farmers market but there is no location of where i can edit that text and wordpress won't let me directly modify the html. So how would i do this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your theme this might be in your theme options or you can check them in widget section under appereance tab in left side of your wordpress admin panel.

Please comment belpw this answer if you are not able to find the text.

Comment: ya it is not under widget section. The widget section only has the red widgets on the bottom so i don't know whereto find it

Comment: Well please check the static page from the admin

Comment: where can i find that. Sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: okay i found that but still nothing. this is so weird

Comment: Well in this case I need to check your admin details or you may also find it from the documentation provided to you.